Is it possible to add a free GMail account to Outlook to be used via Gmail API?
Google offers nice Microsoft Outlook integration, but only for Google Workspace accounts and not for free Gmail accounts. It is possible to add a free Gmail account to Outlook, but AFAIK, this integration works via IMAP. It is possible in Outlook to take advantage of the Gmail API for free Gmail accounts?
